# Terrafomer Azure import Error --- azurerm_virtual_machine not supported service

Tags: azure, terraform-provider-azure, terraformer

`Hello Team ,

I am trying to import the existing resources running in Azure , In this case in my local windows machine i installed terraformer terraformer-azure-windows-amd64.exe and terraform terraform version
Terraform v1.6.5 on windows_386 , provider registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/azurerm v3.0.0
but unfortunately i faced with below error

```
Error *********************************************************
PS C:\terraformer> .\terraformer-azure-windows-amd64.exe import azure -R dr-rg-infra-northeurope -r azurerm_virtual_machine

2023/12/08 09:13:28 Testing if Obtaining a token from the Azure CLI is applicable for Authentication..
2023/12/08 09:13:28 Using Obtaining a token from the Azure CLI for Authentication
2023/12/08 09:13:29 Getting OAuth config for endpoint https://login.microsoftonline.com/ with  tenant 8eac64b0-XXXXXX
2023/12/08 09:13:29 azurerm importing... azurerm_virtual_machine
2023/12/08 09:13:29 azurerm error importing azurerm_virtual_machine, err: azurerm: azurerm_virtual_machine not supported service
```

I am trying to import the existing resources running in Azure .In this case in my local windows machine i installed terraformer terraformer-azure-windows-amd64.exe and terraform terraform version
Terraform v1.6.5 on windows_386 , provider registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/azurerm v3.0.0
but unfortunately i faced with below error  `

Comment: Provider file terraform {
  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      source  = "hashicorp/azurerm"
      version = "=3.0.0"
    }
  }
}

# Configure the Microsoft Azure Provider
provider "azurerm" {
  features {}

ARM_CLIENT_ID ="1bf5e014-xx"
ARM_CLIENT_SECRET ="PD~8Q~hxxx"
ARM_SUBSCRIPTION_ID ="8928xx"
ARM_TENANT_ID ="8eacxx"

}

Answer (score 0):

```
.\terraformer-azure-windows-amd64.exe import azure -R dr-rg-infra-northeurope -r azurerm_virtual_machine
```

The command you're using to import an existing `Azure Virtual Machine` is not valid.

To import existing `Azure Virtual Machines` you have to use VM`resource id`, refer the [Terraform registry](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/virtual_machine#import).

```json
    terraform {
      required_providers {
        azurerm = {
          source  = "hashicorp/azurerm"
          version = "=3.0.0"
        }
      }
    }
    
    provider "azurerm" {
        features {}
      subscription_id = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
      client_id       = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
      tenant_id       = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
      client_secret   = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
    }
    
     resource "azurerm_virtual_machine" "example" {
      name                = "venkatvm"
      resource_group_name = "vm-RG"
    }
```

You can find the `Resource ID` of the existing`Virtual Machine` by navigating to your `VM`, and then selecting the **JSON View** option.

[image]

**Import Command**

```
terraform init

terraform import azurerm_virtual_machine.azure_vm  "/subscriptions/xxxxxx6-44fb-b5ba-2b83a074c23f/resourceGroups/<RG_NAMe>/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/TESTVM1"
```

**Response:**

[image]

Comment: am facing this error                         ---------------------------PS C:\terraformimport> terraform import azurerm_virtual_machine.azure_vm  "/subscriptions/45XXXXXXXXXX/resourceGroups/DEV-T24/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/SIT-T24-PRESENTATION"
Error: resource address "azurerm_virtual_machine.azure_vm" does not exist in the configuration.

Before importing this resource, please create its configuration in the root module. For example:

resource "azurerm_virtual_machine" "azure_vm" {
  # (resource arguments)
}

PS C:\terraformimport>

Comment: import.tf file terraform {
      required_providers {
        azurerm = {
          source  = "hashicorp/azurerm"
          version = "=3.0.0"
        }
      }
    }
    
    provider "azurerm" {
        features {}
      subscription_id = "XXXX"
      client_id       = "XXXXX"
      tenant_id       = "xxx"
      client_secret   = "xxx"
    }
    
     resource "azurerm_virtual_machine" "sitexamp" {
      name                = "SIT-T24-PRESENTATION"
      resource_group_name = "DEV-T24"
    }

Comment: The above error is encountered due to Virtual Machine module is not defined in import.tf , Kindly add this code and check the same: resource "azurerm_virtual_machine" "azure_vm" { name = "<Existing_your VM _Name>" resource_group_name = "<Existing_ VM_Resource Group Name>" }